# CSS && JavaScript Scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a div with images in it. There are going to be a lot of images so I want to be able to scroll left and right within the div with the use of buttons. I previous had the code working but upon changing the divs from media queried and response to static straight CSS, it no longer scrolls.

html:

```
<div id="maincontent">
        <h3 align="center" > Title </h3>
        <div id="gallery-display">
            <div id="image-1"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div id="image-2"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" /></div>            
            <div id="image-3"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div id="image-4"><img src="image4.jpg" alt="" /></div>     
        </div>
        <div id="gallery-slider-parent">
            <div class="left-slider-button">
                <input  
                    type="button" 
                    value="&#9668;" 
                    onmousedown="scrollDiv('gallery-slider', 3)" 
                    onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" 
                />
            </div>
            <div id="gallery-slider">
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>                 
                <a href="#image-1"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-slider-button">
                <input  
                    type="button" 
                    value="&#9658;" 
                    onmousedown="scrosllDiv('gallery-slider', 3)" 
                    onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body {
                background-color: #000;
            }

            #maincontent {
                width: 960px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
            }

            #gallery-display {
                height: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #000;
            }

            #gallery-display img {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 500px;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            #gallery-display [id^='image']:target img {
                top: 0; 
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 500px;
            }


            #gallery-display [id^="image"] img {
                position: absolute;
                top: -500px;
                border: 0;
                -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
                -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
                -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
                -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
            }

            #gallery-display [id^='image']:target a {
                background: #fff;
                border: 3px solid #333;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
            }

            #gallery-slider-parent {
                background-color: #000;
                position: relative;
                width: 960px;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
            }

            #gallery-slider {
                background-color: #000;
                display: inline;
                width: 94%;
                float: left;
                height: 120px;
                overflow: auto;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            #gallery-slider img {
                height: 75px;
                padding: 15px;
                float: none;
            }

            .left-slider-button input[type="button"]{
                opacity: .7;
                color: #FFF;
                float: left;
                width: 28px;
                border: none;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: #151515;
            }

            .right-slider-button input[type="button"]{
                opacity: .7;
                color: #FFF;
                float: left;
                width: 28px;
                border: none;
                height: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #151515;
            }
```

javascript:

```
var timer1;
function scrollDiv(divId, depl) {
    var scroll_container = document.getElementById(divId);
    scroll_container.scrollLeft -= depl;
    timer1 = setTimeout('scrollDiv("'+divId+'", '+depl+')', 10);
}
```

Comment: Well it does work correctly for me. There's only a small typo in your code, the button in ``div.right-slider-button`` should call the ``scrollDiv`` method with a -3 value for the ``depl`` argument (in the code you gave us, both buttons were scrolling in the same direction). Otherwise it works nicely for me on FF, Safari and Opera Next.